# C#: Does BindingSource.Find account for BindingSource.Filter?

Tags: .net, filter, bindingsource

I'm using a `BindingSource` as data source for a `DataGridView`. The user can filter entries. Internally I use the `BindingSource.Filter` property of course. All works well.

Then I get input from a scanner and need to select the first entry in the list that matches the scanned barcode. Whether filtered or not, the *displayed* list may contain several matching entries. For that, I use `BindingSource.Find`. This worked well as long as the list was not filtered.

Does `BindingSource.Find` search within the filtered data now that I use `BindingSource.Filter` or will it search within the entire data set?

**Disclaimer & Apologies**
If I was allowed to take the scanner from production and connect it to my machine, I'd just have tried it...

I'm at a customer site implementing a quick fix, so I didn't google, because I thought I get an answer here quickly anyways... :-)

Comment: Well, didn't get a reply as quickly as I thought I would, so I threw together a small test tool. Obviously, Find works only on the filtered set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this one out myself, as my comment above explains.